# Unable to Update a field in database

Tags: sql, sqlite, lita

here is the screenshot of query. you can easily see the database fields and my query. It is perfectly fine but when I execute this query, my record is not updating, what is the problem here?
[image]

Structure of my database is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Are You sure there is no misspelling in that where condition? Maybe copy value from table.

Comment: Yes I copied it from the existing record @JanWalczak

Comment: Try to execute select with that condition. Select * from Darood where title = .... . Just to make sure it returns any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing [count] in square brackets or quotes.